# Parameters to exec() function in java

Tags: java, runtime.exec

What all parameters can we give to exec() function. Please give me the link for this which can give me the details of the different parameters that can be executed.. 
All help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It are the same parameters as you would give in the "command prompt". So the answer depends on the command prompt of the underlying operating system you're using. In case of for example Windows XP, you can find documentation [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_o.mspx?mfr=true). Specifically, the list of all commands can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_o.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the parameters for exec in the [Runtime javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).  You can give it pretty much any command you would execute at a shell prompt.

I also found a good JavaWorld article, [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html), that explains its usage.

Comment: @Alexander: I don't know what that means.  Are you having trouble with the link?

Comment: @Bill, it's been touch and go the whole day. I really "love" the pseudo-random id now in the javadoc URL. I guess without id, it's not Oracle-proof :). BTW, +1 for the JavaWorld article.

Comment: @Alexander: Thanks.  That "download" prefix threw me off a bit as well.

Comment: @Bill, I think it's an Oracle requirement, that URL should have at least 20 extra dead weight characters.  For example, if you had any doubts that you are looking for `docs`, they've included it there twice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could describe the issue you are having ?

Look at this link: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html
This one is also good: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html